# Vertical align table header

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I currently have a table that is horizontally and vertically centered. I want to add a header to the table (900px max) (85%) wide and keep the table centered. How can I do this? I am thinking of using a row? Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/ajQaL/

HTML

```
  <div class="containcell"><div class="columnsleft"></div></div>

  <div class="containcell"><div class="columnsright"></div></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.containcell {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width:24%;
}
.tablecontain {
margin:0 auto;
max-width:1000px;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
.columncontainer {
width:85%;
max-width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
display:table;     
}
.blurredwedding {
background-image:url(../img/oakglen.png);
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:none;
background-size:cover;
height:100%;
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
margin-top:100px;
position:relative;
display:table;
}
.columnsleft {
width:90%;
height:400px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);

}
.columnsright {
 width:90%;
 height:400px;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
 box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="blurredwedding">

  <div class="headercotainer">
      <h1 class="tableheader">This is your header</h1>
  </div><!--headercontainer should be added here!-->

  <div class="tablecontain">
    <div class="columncontainer">
      <div class="containcell"><div class="columnsleft"></div></div>

      <div class="containcell"><div class="columnsleft"></div></div>

      <div class="containcell"><div class="columnsright"></div></div>

    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Add css for the container.

```
.headercontainer
    {
    max-width:900px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }
```

and the header itself...

```
.tableheader{
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
    text-align:center;}
```

You *may* also need to add `display:block;` to `.tablecontain` as well, but just make sure the children of .tablecontain aren't inheriting this from it if you do need to add that there.

If you also want to vertically center the header's text, then in `.tableheader` add `line-height:50px;` In other words, set line-height to the height of the .tableheader div.

Comment: After messing with it for a bit the .headercontainer still is floating at the top of the page. I want it to sit right above the columns no matter how big or small the screen size is.

Comment: I have added display:table to the background which prevents the columns overflowing the .blurredwedding div if I shrink the window.

Comment: I don't see any floats in your css.  I don't think I get what you're trying to tell me.  Is your table not at the top of your page?

Comment: .blurredwedding is a full size background div..   .tablecontain is a div for a firefox bug that prevents the table to vertically align:middle   .columncontainer is a table that holds the columns. This div sits vertically and horizontally centered no matter how big or small the screen is. I just want a div or table row to sit right above these columns like a header.

Comment: This div cannot overflow .blurredwedding and it always has to stay right above .columncontainer. It could even be in column container as a row thats as wide as all 3 columns together I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried position:relative; on the table container, and then positon:absolute; left:0; top:-(<-- that's negative, height of .headercontainer) on .headercontainer.  Then in the <h1>'s class do margin:auto;

Comment: wouldn't position (absolute) overflow .blurredwedding when the screen size shrinks?

Comment: .columncontainer is display:table so you cannot use position against it.

Comment: regarding the position relative Unipartisandev if you want to post that as the answer I will validate it. Putting padding on the .columncontainer the height of the header worked perfectly

Comment: If you can't use position against .columncontainer then how did it work?  I've actually gotta run, and I won't be around until later, so I can't modify anything. Hopefully this is has been helpful.

Comment: One last thing.  If you want the elements on the page not to shift around when you zoom in or out, size literally everything using em.  The main container is an exception to this. 1em == 16px.  You'll need a calculator, but it's worth it, trust me.  Do a search on elastic designs in css using em.